# Scala, pattern matching, strings

Tags: string, scala, pattern-matching

Is there way to match strings in scala like this:

```
  def matcher(arg: String) : Expr = {
    case left :: '*' :: right => new Binary("*", left, right)
    case left :: '+' :: right => new Binary("+", left, right)
  }
```

where left and right are have type String?

Comment: Are left and right of fixed length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with extractors:

```
object Mult {
  def unapply(x: String): Option[(String, String)] = x.split("\\*") match {
    case Array(a: String, b: String) => Some(a -> b)
    case _ => None
  }
}

object Add {
  def unapply(x: String): Option[(String, String)] = x.split("\\+") match {
    case Array(a: String, b: String) => Some(a -> b)
    case _ => None
  }
}

def matcher(arg: String) = arg match {
    case Mult(left, right) => Binary("*", left, right)
    case Add(left, right) => Binary("+", left, right)
    case _ => println("not matched")
 }
```

You may also want to implement apply method for each extractor like:

```
def apply(l: String, r: String) = s"$l*$r"
```

but this is not mandatory

Comment: Seems like your solution suited me the most, thank you!

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve your goal by matching on regular expressions.

```scala
trait Expr

case class Binary(op: String, leftOperand: String, rightOperand: String) extends Expr

val mulPattern = "(\\d*)\\*(\\d*)".r
val addPattern = "(\\d*)\\+(\\d*)".r

def matcher(arg: String) : Expr = {
  arg match {
    case mulPattern(left, right) => new Binary("*", left, right)
    case addPattern(left, right) => new Binary("+", left, right)
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(matcher("1+2")) // Binary("+", "1", "2")
  println(matcher("3*4")) // Binary("*", "3", "4")
}
```

Comment: could make a method to create those patterns, maybe like this: `def binRegex(symbol: Char) = raw"""([^$symbol]+)[$symbol]([^$symbol]+)""".r`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sir!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so.

You might be able to do it, if you convert the `String` into a `List` or `Vector` of `Char` and then revert the results with `mkString`. But I haven't be able to come up with something.

However, imo, a regular expression would be more concise and readable:

```
trait Expr

case class Binary(op: String, left: String, right: String) extends Expr

val Expression = """(.*?)\s*([+-\/\^\*])\s*(.*)""".r
def matcher(arg: String) : Expr = arg match {
  case Expression(left, op, right) => new Binary(op, left, right)
}

val test = matcher("a + b")
val test2 = matcher("a * b")
```